# SQL - carry previous Application's value onto next Application

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in SQL server, returning the results below, I am having trouble carrying over my SQNCarriedOver Value into the ThisAppOFFICIAL column on the next application.

I cannot do it based on the row number because the Project Names do not list in that order:

[image]

I was wondering if there was a way to carry the QSNCarried over value to the ThisAppOFFICIAL column in the next application with that Project Name,

So for Example:
The thisAppOfficial value on "12/06/2016" would be "10" (from in the QSCarriedOver on "12/05/2016")

I may have overlooked something, I have searched the web but I feel my question is quite specific.

Any help or advice is appreciated, Thank you in advance.

**ps:**
***the next application is the next Application Date with the Same Project Name***

Comment: Can you define more clearly what you mean by 'next application'?  Is it the next row in chronological order for the same Project Name.  So the 9908 should go into the row with the date 22/04/2016 in your first screenshot.  At what point would you expect this value to be copied over, when the new row is inserted?

Comment: the next application is the next Application Date with the Same Project Name @OldBoyCoder

Comment: And when do you want to update the value.  At any point in time or just when a new row is created?

Comment: It must always fill the thisAppOfficial value with the QSCarriedOver value of the Previous Application, No matter what @OldBoyCoder

Comment: OK that makes things harder as you need to consider a lot of scenarios.  What if a new row was added with a date between two existing rows?  What if you delete a row?  What if you edit the QSCarriedOver on an existing row?  If all of these are possible in your application then one way would be to have a TRIGGER on the table that would be fired whenever a row is created, updated or deleted, it can then patch up the values as necessary.  If this sounds like what you want then I can look at coding an example.

Comment: A new row would not be added I can assure, I would assume that rows will not be deleted/added ect., I would want to do this within a select instead of Using a trigger if posible. @OldBoyCoder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce6b2/4)**

```
SELECT t.Project,
       t.AppDate,
       t.thisAppOfficial,
       COALESCE((SELECT TOP 1 t2.QSCarriedOver
        FROM X t2
        WHERE t2.Project = t.Project
        AND t2.AppDate < t.AppDate
        ORDER BY t2.AppDate desc), 0) as NewColumn,
       t.QSCarriedOver
FROM X t
```

Result:

```
| Project |    AppDate | thisAppOfficial | NewColumn | QSCarriedOver |
|---------|------------|-----------------|-----------|---------------|
|       A | 2016-04-13 |              30 |         0 |             0 |
|       A | 2016-05-12 |              30 |         0 |            10 |
|       A | 2016-06-12 |              30 |        10 |             0 |
|       A | 2016-07-12 |              30 |         0 |             0 |
```

Comment: That's better than my solution.

Comment: this is great, do I not need to do a convert(date,Applicationdate,103) each place it references it?

Comment: No, this query gonna work if Applicationdate column type is date

Answer (score 1):

I think I've got what you want and I'm sure that there is a better way of doing it.  I've created a simpler version of your table for my needs.  I then use ROW_NUMBER to put the rows into a sequence so I can do a sort of self-join to the previous row to get the carry forward figure

```
CREATE TABLE X (Project varchar(50), AppDate  date, thisAppOfficial int, QSCarriedOver int)
inserT INTO X VALUES('A', '13 Apr 2016', 30,0)
inserT INTO X VALUES('A', '12 May 2016', 30,10)
inserT INTO X VALUES('A', '12 Jun 2016', 30,0)
inserT INTO X VALUES('A', '12 Jul 2016', 30,0)

SELECT X0.Project, X0.AppDate, X0.thisAppOfficial, X0.QSCarriedOver, ISNULL(X2.QSCarriedOver,0) as 'Brought forward from previous row'  FROM X X0
JOIN (select ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY Project, AppDate) as MainRow, * from X) X1 ON X1.Project = X0.Project AND X1.AppDate = X0.AppDate
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY Project, AppDate) as PrevRow, * FROM X) X2 ON X2.Project = X1.Project and X2.PrevRow = MainRow -1
order by Project, AppDate
```

Have a try with this and see if it is doing what you need, I'm not 100% sure I've understood your requirements so no problem if it isn't what you want.

Comment: this is brilliant, how easy would it be for me to implement the logic for other columns, for example: If I wanted to do the same logic but use another column instead of QSCarriedOver?